# Why does the Stack Exchange site prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed?

Tags: support, questions

Most other sites seem to have questions that can only be discussed or answered.

Comment: Why should we be like most other sites?

Comment: @Rubisco Most other sites have both of them, too.

Comment: I really don't understand the issue here. We wanted to keep things more objective than other sites did. Please state it clearly if you have an objection to that. Right now I'm wondering whether this short oneliner of yours is something loaded and you came back from a less ideal experience on one of the sites, or you just want to be philosophically general.

Comment: [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/), and SE was specifically started *because* most other sites were doing a bad job with their design.

Comment: @NathanTuggy This is a real question

Comment: ... To understand what @NathanTuggy is saying, you need to follow the link. You are asking us to ignore the central principle of what defines SE. It isn't going to change.

Answer (score 4):

Because SE said so. Literally. In the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) (please please please read it for more information), it promptly states to not ask questions that:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Thus it has already been a rule to not ask questions that require discussion except for some cases that must have discussion like in metas. In those cases, they have a specific tag: [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion). Of course, only certain discussions are allowed like those that are used by moderators or SE employees to get user feedback on new updates.

Anyways, Stack Exchange sites are ***Q/A*** sites. That basically means ask question, get ***answers***.

> Most other sites seem to have questions that can only be discussed or answered.

Commonly, there will be no "discussed" with these questions. So actually you should only say that for the meta sites, where one of the four mandatory tags you must use is [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion). So overall, SE doesn't ***prefer*** for questions to be answered not discussed but SE ***demands*** it. Even in discussion questions, you technically can answer the question but there are separate guidelines for those types of questions.